# How to set json array index as bound parameter in sqlite3?

Tags: c, json, sqlite, sqlite-json1

I am using the **C-API** for **SQLite3** and the **json1** extension. Within the database, a list of integers is stored as a **json_array**. I want to create a C integer array from the json_array using the **json_extract** function. I am looping over each value in the json array by incrementing the index in the SQL statement. As an example, consider:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable ( label INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, list TEXT);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ( 1, json(json_array(1,2,3)) ); 

SELECT json_extract( list, '$[index]' ) FROM mytable WHERE label == 1;
---Example: the result for index=0 is the integer: 1
```

In the C program, I am currently creating a character string to represent the **single-quoted** portion of the command, `'$[index]'`, as a bound parameter, as shown in the snippet below.

Can or should I avoid using `sprintf` to set the index? Or, is this an acceptable solution?

```
char *sql = "select json_extract(list, ?) from mytable where label == 1";
char *index_param = (char *)malloc(80);

// OTHER STUFF: prepare sql stmt, etc, etc...

for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {  /* n is the number of values in the json list */

    /* Is sprintf the best thing to do here? */
    index_length = sprintf(index_param, "$[%d]", i);

    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, index_param, index_length+1, SQLITE_STATIC);
    result = sqlite3_step(stmt);
    values[i] = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0);
    sqlite3_reset(stmt);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could construct the path in SQL so that you have only an integer parameter:

```sql
SELECT json_extract(list, '$[' || ? || ']') FROM ...
```

But it would be a better idea to read the array values directly with the [json_each()](http://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jeach) function:

```
const char *sql = "SELECT value FROM MyTable, json_each(MyTable.list) WHERE ...";
// prepare ...
for (;;) {
    rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
    if (rc != SQLITE_ROW)
        break;
    values[i++] = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0);
}
```

Comment: The **json_each()** fcn is very useful and your answer led me to the solution! However, to get the proper behavior I used `if (rc == SQLITE_DONE) break;` instead of `!=`.

Comment: Sorry, that should have been ROW. With DONE, it would never end after an error.